# List all entries in a PostgreSQL datatable

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, psql

While using the psql in the command line, how do I view all entries in a datatable?

The database name is newproject.

```
newproject=#
```

I have tried \l (but this list all the databases)

I am trying to see all the entries in the datatable.  I am trying to verify that the test entries I have been putting in from my web app are storing correctly.

Comment: Define "entry". A database is a catalog of relations (_tables_). Do you mean "Selecting all rows in a given table"?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan after figuring this out, I agree it is a beginner question.  But while someone is learning, and trying to figure out the lay of the land, your comments aren't helping anyone.  I asked this, not because of a sql statement, but I wasn't 100% sure how things work in psql.  Thanks for putting a noobie down, hope you feel smart.

Comment: @user630581: `psql` is the name of the default command line terminal. The name of the RDBMS is PostgreSQL or Postgres for short.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, that does clear up some questions I had.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `\dt` will show all tables in the database. Anyway, you can type `\?` to show available commands.

Selecting every row in a table is just a basic SQL command :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

Comment: _Anyway, you can type `\?`_ is what I was looking for. Voted up.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "your_table";` will work. Quotes are needed when your table name is a keyword like `user`